# Recording audio on the web and sending the data to Android app

Tags: audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, web-mediarecorder

I want to capture audio in the Chrome web browser using `MediaRecorder` and send the encoded audio data to the Android app for playback in real-time.

I can't find any audio format that is supported on both sides. I was trying to use `opus` codec, but Chrome only supports `webm` container, and Android supports `ogg`.

What is the proper way of doing this? I don't want to use WebRTC. I could use some data converters/encoders, but all libraries I found are obsolete/abandoned/insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webm container format is sometimes stored in .mkv files.

Android 5+ eats pretty much any webm the Chromium `MediaRecorder` class delivers. If you give `MediaRecorder`  a MediaStream that came from `getUserMedia()`, and ask it for the right MIME type, you'll get Opus boxed inside webm.

```
const mediaRec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'})
```

If you put that into a file, use `name.webm` or `name.mkv` to name it.  Android has been able to handle it for a long time now.

The [mkvtoolnix program](https://mkvtoolnix.download/index.html) helps you examine these webm files to see what's in them.

If this didn't address your question, please make a comment.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I can use mkv and webm interchangeably. I was sure that those containers are different. My assumption was based on:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#audio-formats, where it is mentioned that the opus can be wrapped with mkv or ogg.

After reading more in this topic I found this: 
"All WebM files are MKV files, but not all MKV files are consistent with WebM."